# Linux, comparing file contents to text string

Tags: linux, echo, wget, contain

I'm having trouble with this bit of linux code:

```
 FILE=$(wget 'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ru72h4b984qpxxq/spotify.txt' -q -O -)

if [ "$FILE" == "|  |" ]
then
echo "File is a match"
```

I can't get this statement to be true.  Would you mind checking the contents of the url and tell me if I'm doing something wrong with the vertical lines or spacing?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `[` command uses `=` for equality testing of strings, not `==`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@MarkB's point is well taken:  one usually uses the `=` single-equals in `[]`.  However, the specific problem in your case seems to be that `wget` is returning a stray `\r` carriage-return character.  You can see this by

```
echo "$FILE" | hexdump -C
```

assuming that you have BSD utilities installed (which you probably do).

Here's one fix:

```
FILE=$(wget 'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ru72h4b984qpxxq/spotify.txt' -q -O - | sed 's/\r//')
```